# Convert html table to json with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup

I am trying to convert HTML table to json using beautifulsoup() function python, I was able to convert but the data coming in wrong json format.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

reading_table = """\
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span class="customlabel">Energy Source</span></td>
<td><span class="custominput">EB</span></td>
<td><span class="customlabel">Grid Reading </span></td>
<td><span class="custominput">2666.2</span></td>
<td><span class="customlabel">DG Reading </span></td>
<td><span class="custominput">15.5</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="customlabel">Power Factor</span></td>
<td><span class="custominput">0.844</span></td>
<td><span class="customlabel">Total Kw</span></td>
<td><span class="custominput">0.273</span></td>
<td><span class="customlabel">Total KVA</span></td>
<td><span class="custominput">0.34</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="customlabel">Average Voltage</span></td>
<td><span class="custominput">241.7</span></td>
<td><span class="customlabel">Total Current</span></td>
<td><span class="custominput">1.54</span></td>
<td><span class="customlabel">Frequency Hz</span></td>
<td><span class="custominput">50</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
"""

reading_table_data = [
    [cell.text for cell in row("td")]
    for row in BeautifulSoup(reading_table, features="html.parser")("tr")
]

print(reading_table_data)
```

The above code prints JSON in the below format.

```
[['Energy Source', 'EB', 'Grid Reading ', '2666.2', 'DG Reading ', '15.5'], ['Power Factor', '0.844', 'Total Kw', '0.273', 'Total KVA', '0.34'], ['Average Voltage', '241.7', 'Total Current', '1.54', 'Frequency Hz', '50']]
```

I would like to get it in below format

```
[
  'Energy Source': 'EB',
  'Grid Reading ': '2666.2'
  'DG Reading ', '15.5',
  'Power Factor', '0.844',
  'Total Kw', '0.273',
  'Total KVA', '0.34',
  'Average Voltage', '241.7',
  'Total Current', '1.54',
  'Frequency Hz', '50'
]
```

Some help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you want is not a valid format, so you can print it after converting the dict to string and replacing the braces.

Here is the working code:

```
    tds = BeautifulSoup(reading_table, features="html.parser").findAll("td")
    data = {}
    for td in tds:
        if "customlabel" in td.span.get("class"):
            attr_key = td.span.text
            data[attr_key] = ""
        if "custominput" in td.span.get("class"):
            attr_value = td.span.text
            data[attr_key] = attr_value
    print(json.dumps(data).replace("{", "[").replace("}", "]"))
```

Comment: right, only using print(json.dumps(data) made it correct. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are reading the cell value of each td. What you need is to differentiate between key and value depending on the css class of the td. After that you will need to use dictionary comprehension rather than list comprehension.